# how to create a Laravel backpack Custom button with livewire

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am trying to make a custom button with livewire but can't get it to work

here is my button blade file

```
@once
  @push('befor_styles')
  <livewire:styles/>
  @endpush
@endonce

@livewire('component')

@once
  @push('after_scripts')
    <livewire:scripts/>
  @endpush
@endonce
```

Here is my livewire blade file

```
<button wire:click="connect" class="btn btn-sm btn-link m-0 text-danger">Connect</button>
```

And the php

```
public function connect()
    {
        $this->message = 'connected';
    }
```

When I click on the button nothing happens. There are no ajax requests being made.

have also tried

```
<livewire:styles/>

@livewire('component')

<livewire:scripts/>
```

This creates an ajax request when the page loads but nothing happens when the button is clicked.

I am using laravel 8 and PHP 7.4

Comment: Hmm do you push the styles and scripts inside the layout blade file? Or inside the button file itself?

Comment: Keep in mind that the button blade file is loaded by Datatables using AJAX, it’s not onpage at first pageload.

Comment: Ah ok I have been adding in the button blade file. so how do I add it to a CRUD blade fill?

Comment: Not to worry. I have figured it out. Thank you @tabacitu

Comment: @tabacitu I have tried publishing blank.blade.php file and added the livewire scripts and styles. But still no luck. I can see that the styles and scripts have been added and the button shows when I load the page but nothing happens when I click. I have tested the livewire scripts outside of backpack and it works fine.

Comment: @tabacitu I have managed to get it working in the show view but still not working as a line button on the list view. Witch is where I would prefer it to be

Comment: your before_styles is spelled wrong by the way